# jQuery slideToggle bouncing due to iFrame

Tags: jquery

I have a button within the DOM that, when clicked, reveals a hidden div using the slideToggle method of jQuery.

The hidden div is updated periodically using AJAX and jQuery to display a Tweet.  Twitter provides code to embed the Tweet as a blockquote and then a script to get the nicely displayed Tweet in an iFrame. This all happens while the div is hidden. So, when the slideToggle method is called it doesn't know how tall the div is and therefore it overshoots creating an ugly bounce effect.

Are there any ways to get rid of this?  Keep in mind, that the height of the div will change depending on the Tweet, so a height cannot be hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't need to know the height of the hidden div, you can just do a slideToggle, it will open the div at it's full height :)

http://jsfiddle.net/3fyamqLk/

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function (e) {

    $('#hidden').stop().slideToggle();

    return false;
});
```

Maybe you have something else going on that makes the bouncing, I can't tell without seeing some code :)

Comment: Right but because of the iFrame being inserted while its hidden, there is a bounce that happens.

Comment: You could try to add stop before the slideToggle to stop all events going on in that element :) Try with the code from the edited answer. It would be much easier if you could recreate the bouncing in fiddle :)